# C++, ShellExecute a URL with the hash sign (#)

Tags: c++, hash, shellexecute

I use ShellExecute to open links from my program. It works fine, but not for all links. When the link has the hash sign (#), the link still opens, but not full (it's cut before the #).
The code I'm using is:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"http://blablabla.com/something#something", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I also tried:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "rundll32.exe", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://blablabla.com/something#something",NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

with the same result.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe it's an issue with your browser? Also note that your sample code does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the "L" before http address. I was using wstring.c_str() in the orginal code.
I use Google Chrome as the browser on Windows 10.

Comment: You should move your edit into an answer (you can and should answer your own question if you found the answer) and accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I added the answer now, but I can "accept it" in 2 days (a message with this information displays).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, after I read a similar question: [ShellExecute fails for local html or file URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305322/shellexecute-fails-for-local-html-or-file-urls)

Then using: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607833/Where-is-the-Default-Browser-Command-Line-in-Regis
I identified the default Internet Browser location, and I made a function:

```
std::size_t hhhel2 = linknewone.find("#");
    if (hhhel2 != std::string::npos) {
        LPTSTR pszBrowserPath;
        if (GetDefaultBrowserLaunchPath(&pszBrowserPath))
        {
            string browserpathWithLink = pszBrowserPath;
            if (browserpathWithLink.length() > 1) {
                string browserpathWithLinkTemp = browserpathWithLink.substr(0, 1);
                    std::size_t dfdX = browserpathWithLinkTemp.find("\"");
                    if (dfdX != std::string::npos) {
                        browserpathWithLink = browserpathWithLink.substr(1);
                    }
                std::size_t dfd = browserpathWithLink.find("\"");
                if (dfd != std::string::npos) {
                    browserpathWithLink = browserpathWithLink.substr(0, dfd);

                }
            }
            delete[] pszBrowserPath;
            ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), browserpathWithLink.c_str(), linknewone.c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem with a simpler method in a QT Applicaiton. When I didn't add the "file:///" to string, it truncates after the sharp character in the url.

```
QString currentpath = QDir::currentPath();
QString url = "/help//html/index.html#current";
QString full_url = "file:///" + currentpath + url;
QByteArray full_url_arr= full_url.toLocal8Bit();
LPCSTR lp = LPCSTR(full_url_arr.constData());
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", lp, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Welcome on the SO! Please explain, how your answer works and how does it solve the problem. Snippet-only answers are not very high quality.