# Prevent java from opening a browser

Tags: java, browser

I want to run the tool ChromHMM locally, which opens a web browser after finishing the calculations. The tool uses

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse((new File(...)).toURI())
```

and it doesn't have a parameter to prevent that behavior.

Comment: Is this a jar file you're running locally for personal use? Or is this a dependency you're pulling in with a tool like maven/gradle? Please include some additional information in your question, such as what you are trying to do, and what program you are using.

Comment: Which command are you running exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ChromeHMM GitHub account there is [a relevant issue](https://github.com/jernst98/ChromHMM/issues/1) from 2017 that lists several solutions:

This:

```
unset DISPLAY && java -mx1600M -jar $chromhmm LearnModel -s 1 -p $threads -nobrowser $binariesdir $modelsdir $num_states $assembly
```

Or specifying `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

`java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ChromHMM.jar LearnModel -nobrowser <inputdir> <outputdir> <numstates> <assembly>`

Weirdly, I found also this comment:

> The '-nobrowser' flag skips the launching of the web browser but not the generation of emission parameters images.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe this is also a bug, because even with -nobrowser chromHMM is opening a browser. I will contact the developer.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question with the exact command, maybe it is just a matter of wrong position of the option... Also, it would people later. Also, which solution worked for you exactly? unset DISPLAY or the java -D option?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The OP pointed out that this solution is wrong, I am leaving it for reference:

> -nobrowser doesn't produce browser files. A bit confusing, but it has nothing to to with opening a webbrowser after finishing the calculations

---

There is a `-nobrowser` option, as documented in the [ChromHMM User Manual](http://compbio.mit.edu/ChromHMM/ChromHMM_manual.pdf)
.

> -nobrowser – If this flag is present, then browser files are not printed. If -nobed is requested then browserfile
>   writing is also suppressed.

So the command would be:

`java -jar ChromHMM.jar LearnModel -nobrowser <inputdir> <outputdir> <numstates> <assembly>`

Comment: -nobrowser doesn't produce browser files. A bit confusing, but it has nothing to to with opening a webbrowser after finishing the calculations.

Comment: Too bad! But does still try to open the browser, even if there are no browser files?

Comment: Yes, browser files are some internal ChromHMM thing. The webbrowser just displays some analysis summary.

Comment: "Also upon termination webpage is created called webpage_NUMSTATES.html
(or webpage_NUMSTATES_outfileID.html if a outfileID is specified) summarizing all the files and images created, and if a
browser can be found, then is automatically opened with this file"

So, depending on the OS, it is enough to disable browser opening. But there must be a batch mode.

Comment: Which ChromHMM command are you using? It seems that LearnModel calls a browser, but maybe there is a similar command, or combination, that generates the same output.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the default browser setting from the registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations\(http|https)\UserChoice
```

[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32355457/7126740)

Comment: You are assuming the OP uses Windows.

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti True. The same strategy would presumably work on other OSes.