# How can I detect if Microsoft Edge is installed?

Tags: c#, windows, registry, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm writing a windows form application (c#) and I need to detect whether the user have "Microsoft-Edge" installed in his/her machine or not.

I'm currently using this registry location:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_20.10240.16384.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe]
"Path"="C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

With a `regex` after the "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge". If the "path" exist then I know edge is installed.

Is there a better way to detect edge? would it be better if I detect that I'm running on Windows 10 and by default Win10 come with edge? What is the best way for that?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 comes with Microsoft Edge and I don't think you can uninstall Edge from it, and you definitely can't install it in previous versions of Windows

Comment: I was looking for a way to doing exactly what you wanted to do. And I found that your method is for me by far the best.
If future versions of Windows drop Edge, your code will still work.
Presuming of the presence of a feature based on the version of the OS is really not better than testing the existence of the feature itself.
I just hope this key is the best one ;)
Cheers.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that.
Please update if you find a better one :)

Comment: You actually can uninstall Microsoft Edge. It's a package app like everything else.

[http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-491534.shtml](http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-491534.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relevant to 15.11.2016:**

The only way that I found working is to use this registry location:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_20.10240.16384.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe]
"Path"="C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

With a `regex` after the "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge".

If the "path" exist then I know edge is installed.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to have a small program getting that version number:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string EdgeVersion = string.Empty;
        //open the registry and parse through the keys until you find Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge
        RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages");
        if (reg != null)
        {
            foreach (string subkey in reg.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (subkey.StartsWith("Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge"))
                {
                    //RegEx: (Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_)(\d +\.\d +\.\d +\.\d +)(_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe])
                    Match rxEdgeVersion = null;
                    rxEdgeVersion = Regex.Match(subkey, @"(Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_)(?<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe)");
                    //just after that value, you need to use RegEx to find the version number of the value in the registry
                    if ( rxEdgeVersion.Success )
                        EdgeVersion = rxEdgeVersion.Groups["version"].Value;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Edge Version(empty means not found): {0}", EdgeVersion);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thank you for the registry link for finding the version number.

Comment: A direct paste of this code worked fine for me on getting the edge version.  Microsoft Edge version=41.16299.492.0

Comment: I just tested this on Windows 10. It did return `Edge Version(empty means not found): 44.19041.423.0`. But, when I start Microsoft Edge (Chromium) and check the About window it says: `Version 86.0.622.56 (Official build) (64-bit)`. So I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the desktop or mobile version of Windows 10 then Edge is pre-installed and can't be uninstalled.

To detect if running on Windows 10 use the [System.Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx) property or the [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx). (See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you want to detect the default browser you should see [How to determine the Windows default browser (at the top of the start menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177957/how-to-determine-the-windows-default-browser-at-the-top-of-the-start-menu)

Comment: [Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/System/Windows/InterOp/OSVersionHelper.cs,d648c1ad87b92a5e) is some interesting reference to detect Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to other answers: my installation of Windows 10 does not have this key:  `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_20.10240.16384.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe`

In:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages\]
```

Instead, it has the following keys:

```
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_38.14393.0.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_40.15063.674.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

The following code could be used to detect if Edge is installed:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var edgeFound = false;
        using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Packages\"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (var subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    if (subkey.StartsWith("Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_"))
                    {
                        edgeFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write(edgeFound);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```