# How can I check the version of the new Microsoft Edge Chromium from inside my C# application?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a way to check the version of Edge Chromium installed on a PC from inside a C# application? I searched before I posted and in a comment on this thread one person had a method for getting the version number from a legacy version of Microsoft Edge: [How can I detect if Microsoft Edge is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594401/how-can-i-detect-if-microsoft-edge-is-installed).

I'm looking for a solution that does exactly that, but for the new Edge Chromium browser.

Comment: Here is a Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822766/how-to-check-if-microsoft-edge-chromium-is-installed-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, I'll give what's in the thread a shot and see if I get anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but maybe that's because I don't what the 3) Check Psuedocode step is asking me to do. For me this solution only finds my old version of edge, 44.18362.449.0. (This is also the solution the method I mentioned in my link above retrieved. My PC currently has version 83.0.478.54 installed.

Comment: i found the Edge Chromium Version under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon, but i think there is probably a better way to find the Version ;-)

Comment: Good find! That's way more of an answer than I had before. Using it until something else comes along, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the Edge Chromium Version under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    private string GetBrowserVersion()
    {
        var localMachine = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{56EB18F8-B008-4CBD-B6D2-8C97FE7E9062}";
        var edgeVersion = Registry.GetValue(localMachine, "pv", null);
        return edgeVersion.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).